# Next office-js planned release date?

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-js, add-in, office-addins

I’ve been working on coming up with a plan to re-write a word vsto as an addin using office-js. Several of the key features would rely on functionality that’s only available in the preview api.

I’m trying to decide whether it’s time to start implementing and waiting for the production release.

Is there any idea of when the current preview features might be ready for use in production?

Comment: hi Fred, glad to know that you are planning your new JS add-in. May I know which kinds of API set you are looking for in the preview version?

Comment: In content controls, I require access to read/write field metadata, and I need to respond to onSelectionChanged. I also need the addin to run on startup and ideally with shared execution context. I think these two things are broken and I am not sure if they are in the next release. The addin I am building is intended to run in Word on as many platforms as possible, including Windows, Mac, and Web to replace our existing VSTO addin written in C#.

Answer (score 1):

The development process takes time, so you could get in time with a new release.

There is no publicly available dates for releases. But I'd recommend attending community calls where MS representatives can answer such questions.

Comment: Ok, good idea! How do I find out about such calls? I would love to participate.

Comment: You can download the calendar invite at https://aka.ms/officeaddinscommunitycall .